# How to render React class to window.document.body for testing purposes?

Tags: reactjs

Using `renderIntoDocument` does not render element in `window`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import dom from './../dom';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';

describe('ReactOutsideEvent', () => {
    it('captures mousedown event', () => {
        let view;

        view = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<div>
            <div className='outside'>Hello!</div>
        </div>);

        console.log('window.document.body.contains', window.document.body.contains(view));
    });
});
```

How do I make it render to the `window` element?

The intent is to test an event listener thats attached to the `window` object, e.g.

```js
import React from 'react';
import dom from './../dom';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';

describe('ReactOutsideEvent', () => {
    it('captures mousedown event', () => {
        let view;

        view = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<div>
            <div className='outside'>Hello!</div>
        </div>);

        window.addEventListener('click', () => {
            console.log('OK');
        });

        view.querySelector('.outside').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true
        }));
    });
});
```

In the above example `dispatchEvent` does not trigger "OK" console output.

Note that I am using React 0.14.0 where [`renderIntoDocument` returns `DOMNode`](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4692).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply append the generated DOMNode to the `document.body` using `window.document.body.appendChild(view);`, e.g.

```js
import React from 'react';
import dom from './../dom';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';

describe('ReactOutsideEvent', () => {
    it('captures mousedown event', () => {
        let view;

        view = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<div>
            <div className='outside'>Hello!</div>
        </div>);

        window.document.body.appendChild(view);

        window.addEventListener('click', () => {
            console.log('OK');
        });

        view.querySelector('.outside').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true
        }));
    });
});
```

Comment: What js test module is this using? Just React Test utils?

Comment: TypeError: '[object MouseEventConstructor]' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new MouseEvent('click', {
           bubbles: true,
           cancelable: true
         })')

Am getting this error.